# Pandas "DatetimeIndex" is not accurately converting datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a `minute` dataset from: `01.01.2017 00:00:00.000` to `06.10.2017 23:59:00.000`

It looks like this:

```
Gmt time, Open, Close
01.01.2017 00:00:00.000, 1.05148, 1.05153
01.01.2017 00:01:00.000, 1.05148, 1.05153
01.01.2017 00:02:00.000, 1.05148, 1.05153
...., ...., ....
01.01.2017 23:58:00.000, 1.05148, 1.05153
19.06.2017 23:59:00.000, 1.05148, 1.05153
```

now I do (sort the data):

```
df = df.sort_values('Gmt time')
```

and then I do:

```
df['Gmt time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Gmt time'])
```

and then do:

```
df['Gmt time'].describe()
```

I get the wrong `first` and `last` value. Not only that, it looks like `pd.DatetimeIndex` miscalculated it.

The new `first` and `last` values are:

```
first     2017-01-01 00:00:00
last      2017-12-06 23:59:00
```

but my last value was supposed to be `2017-06-19 23:59:00`

what could have caused this to happen?

**TEST CASES:**

I want to add some test cases which may help. If the dataset is a complete Year from: `01.01.2017 00:00:00.000` to `12.31.2017 23:59:00.000` then I have correct values. This dataset is a full year minute data.

Comment: Did you parse it with the `dayfirst` parameter? That defaults to False, but it looks True in your dataset

Comment: @G.Anderson could you please explain it a bit more? what do you mean by `dayfirst` ? here `Gmt time` is the `datetime` timestamp in exactly minute.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html): 
dayfirst : bool, default False ; If True, parse dates in data with the day first order". So try setting that parameter to true since the dates you're parsing are in day-first format (`dd.mm.yyyy` instead of `mm.dd.yyyy`), as follows `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Gmt time'], dayfirst=True)` and see if that helps